# How do you say "backstory" (of a book/game/movie)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am having trouble translating this word in this sentence:

> The **backstory** of the game will be familiar for those who watched the movie.

Here, the backstory is not the story of the game, but what happened before the moment when the game takes place. For example: a war that happened 100 years before the player was born. In English, the *lore* of the game is a common synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Esperanto, the plot of a story is the *intrigo* (and that word also means "intrigue"), and the background is the *fono*. So, a summary of an earlier part of the story could be called a *resumo* or *prologo* or *la antaŭintrigo*, and a discussion of the historical background could be titled *Historia fono* or *Fonrakonto* if it is largely fictional.

> *La historia fono / fonrakonto estos jam konata de tiuj, kiuj spektis la filmon...*

- *Antaŭaj okazoj* — earlier events
- *Antaŭintrigo* — plot from before
- *Antaŭrakonto* — prefatory anecdote
- *Disvolviĝo* — development
- *Elvolviĝo* — elaboration, unwinding
- *Fono* — background, backdrop

  - *Historia fono* — historical background
  - *Fonrakonto* — background story, anecdote
- *Historio* — history
- *Pli frue... / Antaŭe...* — Earlier...
- *Sciaĵoj, antaŭinformoj* — things to know

  - *Sciaro, popolscio* — lore
  - *Sciindaĵoj* — things worth knowing